# NullPointerException in asynctask when parsing JSON

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, android-json

I am parsing json from url, the below code is simplified one which doesn't work. I am getting a NullPonterException at `JSONObject json=jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(GETSCHOOL_URL);`.I found many people have searched for these particular problem, but I couldn't find any solution for my case.

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    AutoCompleteTextView act;

    JSONParser jsonParser;
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String GETSCHOOL_URL = "http://sample.com/json";
    private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new GetSchools().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    class GetSchools extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.d("request!", "starting");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String success;

            try {
                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(
                        GETSCHOOL_URL);
                Log.d("data", json.toString());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        }
    }

}
```

I think its silly mistake that I've done somewhere in program

Answer (score 2):

You're never initializing jsonParser in the code you pasted. It needs to be initialized before your asyncTask is called.